# How to make elements flow under multi-line textbox?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have successfully created a layout that works for me, except one issue, when multi-line text is entered, it overlaps the other EditText fields.  Normally, when I was in a LinearLayout that was only vertical, it worked, and the rest of the content moved down.  But since I added horizontal LinearLayouts in order to get the labels 1,2,3 in, the multi-line boxes no longer force the content to flow around them.

[image: layout]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Begin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/whathappened" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_below="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:minLines="2" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/two"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:minLines="2" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/three"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:minLines="2" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding screenshot of solution:

[image: solution]

Comment: isnt the height of the edit text has to be increased ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way and let me know still have issue...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whathappened"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/whathappened" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="2" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="2" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this does the trick.  Thank you.  I edited your answer and cleaned up the formatting.